# How to extend service in Docker Compose V2?

Tags: architecture, docker, docker-compose

I have three different projects, ProjectA depends on ProjectB, which in turn depends on ProjectC.

Assume you want to develop only ProjectC, so I want to use a setup with one container only at its runtime.

ProjectB needs ProjectC, so I have to define a docker-compose with two images.

ProjectA then again needs both ProjectB and ProjectC, so I fear I have to either duplicate a lot in the each `docker-compose.yml` file the longer the dependency chain gets.

I know I can link external images in a docker-compose.yml, yet this means more manual setup, as I have to checkout each project and run docker-compose.yml in each of them.

Basically I wonder how I can manage a docker-compose setup for a microservice architecture.

For the lack of a better phrase: Can I extend docker-compose.yml files?

Comment: In short I think the answer is currently _no_. `extends` is very limited (see https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1617 https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3220) and there is no `includes`/ `path` or multi-file compose yet (see https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/318 and https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3322)

Comment: Related: [How to extend service in Docker Compose V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52587643/55075)

Answer (score 2):

You can extend services in docker-compose.yml from another YAML file. Just use [extends](https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#extends) key in your docker-compose.yml.

For example:

projectC.yml

```
webapp:
 build: .
 environment:
   - KEY=VALUE
 ports:
   - "8000:8000"
```

projectB.yml

```
web:
  extends:
    file: projectC.yml
    service: webapp
```

Comment: The current extend system seems to be quite restrictive as `services with 'links' cannot be extended`. [There's an issue for this on github](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1617).

Answer (score 2):

The next release (1.5.0) will support a way to extend a composition (see https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/2051). It is in master now if you want to try it out.

I think what you're describing is pretty close to this proposal https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/318

Answer (score 0):

The [`docker/compose` issue 318](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/318) mentioned in 2016 in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034239/how-to-extend-service-in-docker-compose-v2#comment63110285_33034239) is now (Aug. 2023) resolved.

It is completed by [`compose-spec/compose-spec` PR 363](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/pull/363), and detailed in Docker Desktop 4.22:

> ### [Split complex Compose projects into multiple subprojects with ‘`include`’](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-desktop-4-22/)

> If you’re working with complex applications, use the new `include` section in your Compose file to split your project into manageable subprojects.
>
> Compared to merging files with CLI flags or using extends to share common attributes of a single service from another file, include loads external Compose files as self-contained building blocks, making it easier to collaborate on services across teams and share common dependency configurations within your organization.
>
> For more on how you can try out this feature, read “[Improve Docker Compose Modularity with `include`](https://www.docker.com/blog/improve-docker-compose-modularity-with-include/)” from [Nicolas De Loof](https://twitter.com/ndeloof), or refer to [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/include/).