# How to extend service in Docker Compose V3?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a **`docker-compose.yml`** which looks like

```
version: '2'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=passme
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
      - MYSQL_USER=root

  base:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/proj
    environment:
      - ENV_1=Value_1
      - ENV_2=Value_2
      - ENV_3=Value_3

  worker:
    extends:
      service: base
    command: celery -A proj worker --loglevel=debug
    links:
      - redis
      - mysqldb
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb

  web:
    extends:
      service: base
    links:
      - mysqldb
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Now, I want to ***upgrade*** it to [**version-3**](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).
[From the doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#example-use-case)

> The `extends` keyword is supported in earlier Compose file formats up to Compose file `version 2.1` (see extends in v1 and extends in v2), but is ***not supported in Compose `version 3.x`***

So, here is my question, How can I use Version-3 docker-compose file without losing my current *functionalities*?

Comment: See also the new (Q3 2023) [`include` section in compose 2.20](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76942622/6309)

Answer (score 6):

### Update:

With docker-compose 1.27, `extends` is supported again for version 3:
https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/7588

Comment: is there any plan to officially support this in v3 or is this fleeting compatibility?

Comment: Version is deprecated

https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/a5a952ea97577169fff9f0b26854a9d92c3437ee/spec.md#compose-file

Answer (score 5):

[Extending services](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services) isn't supported in [version 3](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-3) after removal of `extends`.

As for workaround, you can use [`docker-compose addons`](https://github.com/dnephin/compose-addons#dcao-include), e.g.

```
include:
    - http://example.com/compositions/servicea.yaml
    - http://example.com/compositions/serviceb.yaml

namespace: core

web:
    image: example/service_a:latest
    links: ['servicea.web', 'serviceb.api']
```

---

Another way is to include multiple composer files from the command-line (with multiple `-f` options). See: [Add support for multiple composefile when deploying](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/569). E.g.

```
docker-compose -f submodules/A_SUB_PROJECT/docker-compose.yml -f submodules/B_SUB_PROJECT/docker-compose.yml config | docker-compose -f - up
```

<sup>Source: [When using multiple docker-compose.yml files from different directories, local paths are not followed correctly](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3874).</sup>

---

In general, [version 3 is more ideal for Swarm/Kube stacks](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31101#issuecomment-428472115), so consider using it.

E.g.

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mystack1
docker stack deploy -c another/docker-compose.yml mystack2
```

> If you're not using Swarm or Docker Enterprise Kubernetes stacks, there is no reason to use v3. Stick with v2.4, and you get all the `docker-compose` cli features including `extends`, `depends_on`, extension fields, and even `depends_on` with healthchecks (to avoid `wait-for-it` scripts).

---

Related:

- [Include external config](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/758)
- [feature: including external docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/318)
- [Add support for `extends` feature in Compose v3 / docker stack deploy](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31101)
- [extends not supported in version 3 schema](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4315)